# Laravel Deployment -> Cannot find FormRequestServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy my Laravel 8.24 Application on shared hosting (inside a subfolder). I followed [this tutorial.](https://dev.to/fractalbit/deploy-a-laravel-7-app-to-shared-hosting-4eac)
I did everything, I seperated the public folder from the rest of the application and referenced it inside index.php:

```
require '../../partner_files/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once '../..//partner_files/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I also edited the .env file correctly and made the storage softlink. But now, when I open up the URL to the Laravel Application, I receive the following error:

```
Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FormRequestServiceProvider" not found
```

[image: The Laravel error]

Now I am completely lost, I dont even know where this error originates.

Can some Laravel professional out there tell me what could be the cause of this error?
Is something wrong with the paths, as it cannot find the file?

Is there a way to fix this?

### EDIT

I fixed the path, but now , when I call the page, I only receive:

```
{ "name": "symfony/polyfill-php80", "type": "library", "description": "Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.0+ features to lower PHP versions", "keywords": ["polyfill", "shim", "compatibility", "portable"], "homepage": "https://symfony.com", "license": "MIT", "authors": [ { "name": "Ion Bazan", "email": "ion.bazan@gmail.com" }, { "name": "Nicolas Grekas", "email": "p@tchwork.com" }, { "name": "Symfony Community", "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors" } ], "require": { "php": ">=7.1" }, "autoload": { "psr-4": { "Symfony\\Polyfill\\Php80\\": "" }, "files": [ "bootstrap.php" ], "classmap": [ "Resources/stubs" ] }, "minimum-stability": "dev", "extra": { "branch-alias": { "dev-main": "1.22-dev" }, "thanks": { "name": "symfony/polyfill", "url": "https://github.com/symfony/polyfill" } } }
```

Is this a problem with the PHP Version? I am using the same as on localhost

### EDIT 2

My composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "andcarpi/laravel-popper": "^0.9.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.1",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.0",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^9.0.0",
        "ext-gd": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If you dont have access to comand line and cant run composer install, did you copied vendor folder from your PC?

Comment: Sure, I copied the whole vendor folder and the node_modules, I also ran composer install and composer dump-autoload before

Comment: please add the code inside composer.json file to your question

Answer (score 0):

$app = require_once '../..`//`partner_files/bootstrap/app.php';

I see a typo here, shouldn't it be like this:

$app = require_once '../..`/`partner_files/bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: Thank you! Now I receive a different error (check my EDIT)